# Edit text data getting cleared in android when screen goes to off in android 2.2.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am using `EditText` to enter data, but when display turns off and on, then all entered data getting cleared, I am using android version 2.2.2.

My code is here :

```
  public void placeView() {    
        mEditText = new EditText(mContext);

        mTextView = new TextView(mContext);
        mEditText.setSingleLine();
        mEditText.onSaveInstanceState();
        mEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        mTextView.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        mTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mtableRow = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams trLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mtableRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        mtableRow.setLayoutParams(trLayoutParams);
        LayoutParams tvLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LayoutParams edtLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        mEditText.setLayoutParams(edtLayoutParams);
        mTextView.setLayoutParams(tvLayoutParams);

        mTextView.setTextSize(20);
        mtableRow.addView(mTextView);
        mtableRow.addView(mEditText);
        mtableRow.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);    
    }
```

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675384/how-to-create-an-api-for-shipping-extension-to-work-in-android-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try saving the text from the EditText to the shared preferences in

```
onPause()
```

then setting the EditText text from the shared preferences in

```
onResume()
```

Comment: does android have any method like savedInstanceState, so that it should save data automatically and restore

Comment: Yes. However, this will only be used when an Activity is created or destroyed which does not apply in your case.

Comment: Ok How to do it if the activity is created or destroy.